# Real World Application sample throws SecurityException

Tags: c#

I've found a sample on internet accessible here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996475.aspx

I have downloaded the sample and compiled it with C# Virtual Studio 2010, and when compiling it is ok, but at runtime it throws a Security Exception:

```
SingletonCommunicator comm = (SingletonCommunicator)RemotingServices.Connect(typeof(SingletonCommunicator), SingletonCommunicatorUrl);

if (comm.Control == null) 
{
    comm.Control = new SingletonCommunicatorControl();
```

The text for the exception is:

> "Type System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef and the types derived from it
>   (such as System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef) are not permitted to be
>   deserialized at this security level".

Does anyone have encountered such exception, and knows how to fix it ?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

It was just a question of minutes and I found the answer to my own question in the link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxse167(v=vs.85).aspx

You just need to set the TypeFilterLevel to Full before calling the RegisterChannel

```
// Creating a custom formatter for a TcpChannel sink chain.
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider provider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
provider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
// Creating the IDictionary to set the port on the channel instance.
IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
props["port"] = 8085;
// Pass the properties for the port setting and the server provider in the server chain argument. (Client remains null here.)
TcpChannel chan = new TcpChannel(props, null, provider);
```